# replace string with string in a file with bash when string contains "/"

Tags: bash, replace

i have an executable file that is looking for kanwadict here

```
/usr/local/share/kakasi/kanwadict
```

when it should be looking in

```
/home/mrhowtos/public_html/share/kakasi/kanwadict
```

so i want to replace all the

```
"/usr/local/share/kakasi/kanwadict"
```

in the executable file with

```
"/home/mrhowtos/public_html/share/kakasi/kanwadict"
```

also, i dont have privileges to write where its looking, so i cant just move the file its looking for.

i found the cmd to find and replace but its delimiters are "/"

```
sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' *.txt
```

so its not working for me to do this, is there another command that will work to do this?

Comment: If you're talking about a binary executable then a simple find-and-replace will not work. Is there no way to override the location it is looking for using a command line argument or environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

Use alternative delimiter like `#` with sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's#old-word#new-word#g' *.txt
```

for your case it will be:

```
sed -i.bak 's#/usr/local/share/kakasi/kanwadict#/home/mrhowtos/public_html/share/kakasi/kanwadict#g' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `/` character like `\/`;

```
sed -i 's/\/usr\/local\/share\/kakasi\/kanwadict/\/home\/mrhowtos\/public_html\/share\/kakasi\/kanwadict/g' *.txt
```